# Passar valor via $_GET em include_once

Tags: php, include

Preciso passar um valor para uma página que está em um `include_once`, porém não sei como solucionar:

O código que estou usando para includes fica no diretório principal:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_GET["p"])){
                if (file_exists($_GET["p"])){
                    include_once($_GET["p"]);
                } else {
                    include_once("main.php");
                }
            } else {
                include_once("main.php");
            }
?>
```

E a página que quero chamar via $_GET fica dentro do diretório */includes/users/*.

O código abaixo, não redireciona para página `edit.php` apenas recarrega a `main.php`.

```
echo "<td><a class='uk-button' href='index.php?p=includes/users/edit.php?id=$id'><i class='uk-icon-cog'></i> Edit</a>
                        <a class='uk-button uk-button-danger' href='#'><i class='uk-icon-trash'></i> Delete</a></td>";
```

O que não consigo fazer é que a página `edit.php` seja carregada dentro do include quando está com parâmetro ex: `index.php?p=includes/users/edit.php?id=25`. Sem parâmetro a página `edit.php` carrega normalmente.

Imagino que devo adicionar alguma coisa no código do include, mas não encontrei a solução ainda.

Comment: Se é o que entendi, você pode usar a função [header()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) para redirecionar para a página.

Comment: Quem votou como como impossível de reproduzir ou erro de digitação ao menos tentou entender a pergunta?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto eu não votei e sinceramente não percebi nada, nem da pergunta nem da resposta...

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que *querystrings* são pares chave=valor e os valores de cada chave são todos os caracteres compreendidos entre o sinal de igualdade e o conector de múltiplos argumentos (&), se houver mais de um, ou o final da string.

Se você depurar **$_GET['p']** dentro do isset() vai ver que o que está chegando não é **edit.php** e sim **edit.php?id=1**

Basta trocar a segunda interrogação pelo conectivo de múltiplos pares (&) que vai funcionar.

Mas ainda mantenho uma ressalva de isso que tentou fazer nesse código é extremamente perigoso pois poderia permitir que isso acontecesse:

```
arquvo.php?var=http://www.outrosite.com/script_malicioso.php
```

E seu programa executaria sem questionar.

O menos pior a se fazer quando se trabalha com *querystrings* é conhecer previamente os possíveis valores para essa variável que será considerada como arquivo a ser incluído e usar um *path* conhecido por você.

Existem várias formas, mas a mais simples de todas é com N condicionais:

```
if( $_GET['var'] == 'contato' ) {

    $arquivo = 'contato.php';

} else if( $_GET['var'] == 'empresa' ) {

    $arquivo = 'empresa.php';

} else {

    $arquivo = 'main.php';
}

include_once $arquivo;
```

Você pode usar switches que deixarão o código relativamente maior, mas um pouco mais robusto ou arrays que deixará tudo bem pequeno à um custo de perfomrance (infímo, mas presente).

Comment: Então, estou ciente desse risco já. O que não consigo fazer é que a página edit.php seja carregada dentro do include quando está com parâmetro ex: index.php?p=includes/users/edit.php?id=25 A página não abre.

Comment: +1 por exemplificar o risco de segurança

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues você não irá conseguir passar um parametro $_GET através de include. Mas você pode observar que o mesmo já existe no $_GET pois o mesmo é interpretado globalmente. Experimente utilizar o comando echo '<pre>';var_dump($_GET);

Comment: Houve um pequeno erro de compreensão meu quando respondi, agora está corrigido.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto consegui! Eu estava usando outro `?` para passar o valor. E era `&`, não lembrava disso! Vou utilizar provavelmente um switch case como o user Kaminary exemplificou.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Reiterando a questão de segurança: o método `file_exists()` impediu que páginas externas sejam acessadas. Neste caso, imagino, que o include estaria seguro?

Comment: Sim, mas se o invasor injetar um arquivo dentro do servidor, com um exploit, o arquivo vai de fato existir e o include continuará trabalhando quietinho.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código permite falhas graves de segurança por permitir ao usuario exibir livremente qualquer arquivo do servidor.

Recomendo a tentar algo do tipo:

```
<?php
$page = 'main.php';

if (isset($_GET["p"])){
  switch($_GET["p"]){
    case '1':
      $page = 'conteudo.php';
      break;
    case '2':
      $page = 'edit.php';
      break;
  }
}

require_once($page);
?>
```

A solução ainda está ruim, mas já da um nivel de segurança maior para a aplicação.

**Explicando o problema**

Imagine que você tenha um arquivo de configuração com os dados para acesso ao banco de dados, este arquivo se chama exemplo.config;

O que aconteceria se o usuário passasse para o seu código o parametro desta forma: `?p=exemplo.config` ??

Seu código iria incluir o arquivo de configuração e iria mostrar no navegador do usuario o conteudo do arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado @Kaminary, vou utilizar um switch pois acho mais organizado que os if.

Comment: Reiterando a questão de segurança: o método `file_exists()` impediu que páginas externas sejam acessadas. Neste caso, imagino que o include estaria seguro?

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues páginas externas sim, porem no meu exemplo eu utilizo um arquivo de configuração que está no próprio servidor. Neste caso conhecendo o caminho do arquivo eu tenho livre acesso ao mesmo com o seu código;

Comment: Ah! Certo, entendi.